# How to disable TAB key in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-propagation

I want to disable the <kbd>tab</kbd> key in my HTML form. I found following JavaScript code to disable <kbd>tab</kbd>, but it doesn't work in Firefox (working in Chrome and IE).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 9) { // Capture and remap TAB
        window.event.keyCode = 9;
    }
    if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 9) { // New action for TAB
        alert('The TAB key was pressed');
        return false;
    }
}    
</script>
```

This is my HTML form:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='text'><br>
        <input type='submit'><input type='reset'>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: **Please don't.**

Comment: I need to do this, it very important ............in my real program.

Comment: You better have a really good reason for doing so! And even then, it's not recommended. If you really want to, check up on events in the different browsers. Javascript isn't the same everywhere

Comment: If you can post what the problem with TAB is and what you want to accomplish, you might get some interesting alternatives...

Comment: friend sjums, you have any idea or any javascript code ? because i m not that much familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.stopPropogation()` or `event.cancelBubble()` (for certain version of IE) will stop an event from propagating upwards, including the default handler.

As others have said, it's a bad idea to be preventing tab from working properly. From a user's point of view, disabling tab is likely to become very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I've dabbled in allowing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to be used in `textarea`s, perhaps you can derive further from this.

```
<form>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="82"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
function initTabinput() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', tabListener.bind(area), false);
}

var area = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
var tabListener = function (evt) {
    if ('keyCode' in evt && evt.keyCode === 9) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var caretPos = this.selectionStart;
        var beforeCursor = this.value.substring(0, caretPos);
        var afterCursor = this.value.substring(caretPos);

        caretPos += 1;

        this.value = beforeCursor + "\t" + afterCursor;
        this.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', initTabinput, false);
</script>
```

NB. This is absolutely not cross-browser compatible code and has been tested only in recent versions of Chrome.